# I don't use the left most prefix of the indexes,why index is valid in result?

Tags: mysql, indexing

this is the sql

```sql
use test_01;
drop table if exists orders  ;
create table orders(
    id int auto_increment primary key ,
    name char(20) ,
    price decimal(10,2) default 0
);
```

```
alter table orders add key name_price_key(name,price);
explain select price from orders where price=45.80  and   name = 'alisi1900001';
```

this is the explain result

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | orders | NULL | ref | name_price_key | name_price_key | 87 | const,const | 1 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

Comment: where price=45.80  and   name = 'alisi1900001';   .. teh columns in where are the same of the columns in  index name_price_key

Answer (score 0):

"Using index" is the clue.  It means that *all* the columns in the `SELECT` are found in the index.

The leftmost column *is* in the `WHERE`:

```
and name = 'alisi1900001'
```

So, I don't understand what you are asking.

The order of the tests in `WHERE` does not matter; the order of the columns in `INDEX` does matter.  The `WHERE` filters on both `name` and `price`, so the whole index can be used.  Note also "const,const".